# No macro for Power Query in Excel 2013

Tags: vba, powerquery, excel-2013, method-missing

I installed "Power Query" in Excel 2013. Works fine. However it doesn't support VBA. No code is generated when I try to make a macro with the macro recorder. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The fact that the macro recorder doesn't create any code doesn't mean that it is not possible.

Comment: In excel 2016 creation is fine.

Comment: And have you tried to run the code that the recorder created on a computer with 2016 on a computer that runs 2013?

Comment: It doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

> What I am doing wrong?

Using Excel 2013 in 2022. You should upgrade already.

It will work if you upgrade to 2016.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbookquery

> **WorkbookQuery object (Excel)**
>
> An object that represents a query that was created by Power Query. Introduced in Office 2016.

Comment: You can install "power query" in excel 2013. However vba2013 is not quite compatible.

Comment: That is exactly it.